# Foreach within a while loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, while-loop

I'm having an issue with a foreach loop iterating its entire array contents in each instance of the while loop.

I've tried moving the loop, adding break & continue points and using alternate syntaxes-- I feel like I'm just missing something small here.  Do I need to further define the array?  Do I integrate the foreach loop into the while somehow?  Any pointers would be much appreciated.  Here is a basic run down of the code (using "Shopp" an ecommerce plugin with a similar code example at: https://shopplugin.net/api/shopp_cart_items/):

```
<?php  while(shopp('cart','items')): // initializes the shopping cart loop

           $Items = shopp_cart_items(); 
            foreach ( $Items as $item ):

        echo $item->quantity * $item->weight; // multiplies weight by quantity

                endforeach; echo 'g'; endwhile; ?>
```

The products are measured in weight, so as an example, there are 2 items in the cart with their weights at 1 gram, and 2 grams respectively.

**Here's the current output:**

Cart item 1 - Weight: 12g
Cart item 2 - Weight: 12g

**Here's the expected output:**

Cart item 1 - Weight: 1g
Cart item 2 - Weight: 2g

Thanks in advance!

IH

**Edit:**

There is no documentation in Shopp concerning product weight, so I had to find the product object and arrays and added an ++ operator to cycle through them with each while iteration.  Here is the code I used.

echo $Items[$i++]->option->dimensions['weight'] * shopp('cartitem','quantity', 'echo=false');

with the integer set outside the loop: $i = 0;

Comment: Please add a language tag.

Comment: I don't understand why there are two looping structures in play here.  What is your intent in doing that?

Comment: Looks like you are printing both item weight for each item. Seems that only one loop would be enough

Comment: Drop the while(shopp(...)) line. That call does nothing but confuse you. The example you site doesn't even show the while loop.

Comment: The first loop is the cart items loop, where each cart item's details are instanced.  It does seem logical that only one loop is required, but using the code "echo $item->quantity * $item->weight;" without the loop doesn't return anything!

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $item->quantity * $item->weight; // multiplies weight by quantity
```

is probably returning improperly, but could be as simple as

```
echo ($item->quantity * $item->weight);
```

I'd also recommend using something besides Item as $item $Item and $items is getting really confusing to look at.

Comment: operand operator operand - there is nothing which is ambiguous with such expressions - no parenthesis required.

Answer (score 0):

another approach

```
  $product_id = shopp('cartitem.get-product');
  $weight = shopp('product.get-weight'); // use product tag to get weight
  $quantity = shopp('cartitem.get-quantity'); // use cart-item tag to get quantity
  echo $weight * $quantity .' g';
```

Comment: It looks you are mixing old syntax (`shopp('cart','items')`) togather with new syntax (`shopp('cart.items')`).
New syntax of cart.items is exampled here:
https://shopplugin.net/api/cart-hasitems/

Comment: I have adjusted it, but there is no old and new syntax. The 'new' one is just a shorthand version. Mixing the two doesn't result in errors. When you look at the core Shopp code you will find both notations are used. Eventually every `shopp()` command in the core code will be replaced with the shorthand version of course.